# How do I write a Django view that can be called by jQuery's $.getJSON()?

Tags: python, django

The javascript:

```
$.getJSON('/jsonView', {
    tag: "userName",
    userName: 'zjm1126'
}, function (H) {
    if (H.result == "successName") {
        F.showOk(h.ok);
    } else {
        if (H.result == "existName") {
            F.showErr(h.userNameExist);
        }
    }
});
```

The view:

```
def jsonView(request):
    # What would go here?
```

---

```
def json_view(request):
  import json
  username=request.GET.get('username')
  result='successName'
  if username:
    try:
      user=User.objects.get(username=username)
      result='existName'
    except User.DoesNotExist:
      pass
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'result': result}))
```

it makes 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.

why???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is relatively straightforward

```
def json_view(request):
  username=request.GET.get('username')
  result='successName'
  if username:
    try:
      user=User.objects.get(username=username)
      result='existName'
    except User.DoesNotExist:
      pass
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'result': result}))
```

Comment: hi czarchaic, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092566/how-do-i-write-this-django-viewjsonview-it-is-used-getjsonjquery/2098847#2098847

Comment: hi czarchaic,see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099345/why-1-is-ok-but-2-is-error-use-django-and-jquery 

the email is not ok.
thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you work your way through James Bennett's tutorial on using [AJAX with Django](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jul/31/django-tips-simple-ajax-example-part-1/) - he includes details on writing views that return JSON.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple:

1. Retrieve GET data from request.GET
2. Do stuff
3. Return a response with mimetype `application/javascript`

1 and 2 are like any other view. If you don't know how to do 3, check out [`django.http.HttpResponse.__init__`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/http/__init__.py#L276)